# Package By Feature and SONAR says dependency cycle

Tags: java, dependencies, package, sonarqube

Currently im working on a java webapplication project. And we use sonar to monitor our code quality.

The java project is somewhat structured in the way of package by feature. An example of the issue in sonar:

```
com.company.webapp.page
    BasePage.java

com.company.webapp.page.feature1
    Feature1Page.java (extends BasePage)
    XComponentFeature1.java
    YComponentFeature1.java
    ZComponentFeature1.java

com.company.webapp.page.feature2
    Feature2Page.java (extends BasePage)
    XComponentFeature2.java
    YComponentFeature2.java

com.company.webapp.page.feature3
    Feature3Page.java (extends BasePage)
    WComponentFeature3.java
    XComponentFeature3.java
    YComponentFeature3.java
    ZComponentFeature3.java
```

In sonar they all say voor packages feature 1 to 3 has a dependency to cut with package page.BasePage.java. Any ideas how i could structure the package to solve this sonar issue?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question relates to this known Sonar limitation : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3452

Comment: For the time being i will accept this answer. Too bad there hasn't been any activity on this issue since 2008